# Sorting excel table by dates of events (sometimes 1day sometimes dd1.-dd2.mm.yyyy)

Tags: excel, sorting, date

I have to sort a table of events by date, what is working fine as long as I have only singe day events. But as I am having as well events going over several days it isn't working anymore.

I guess the main problem is, that excel doesn't recognize the dd. - dd.mm.yyyy as a date. 
(I am using the German dd.mm.yyyy format and that is working fine with the single day dates, but I wouldn't mind using a different format)

```
01. - 04.06.2016
21. - 22.04.2016
25.5.2016
10.10.2016
28.11. - 02.12.2016
```

the single dates are right-aligned (recognized as dates) the from-till dates are left-aligned (not recognized)

Comment: You will need two columns one for the start or single date and one for the end or blank.  Then sort on the first.  Or change every thing to text with full dates in the form of `yyyy.mm.dd`.

Comment: I assume that you have 4 different formats here? `"dd.MM.yyyy"`, `"dd. - dd.MM.yyyy"`, `"dd.MM. - dd.MM.yyyy"`, `"dd.MM.yyyy - dd.MM.yyyy"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dd.mm.yyyy format will be stored as a date which sorts correctly. The dd. - dd.mm.yyyy date ranges will be stored as text and sorted based on the characters.

You need to either split date ranges into 2 columns with the starting date in the first column along with the single dates; or change the format of the dates and ranges.

To keep everything in one cell, you would need to first change cells to Text formatting and enter everything as:

yyyy.mm.dd

yyyy.mm.dd - .dd